# Using Regular Value Theorem to Show that $S^2$ is a $2$-dimensional Manifold.

Tags: manifolds, implicit-function-theorem

If we let $F(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2-1$. Then we know that $DF = (2x,2y,2z)$.  I am confused as to how I should show that $0$ is a regular value of this function.  I think I am missing something very simple.  Is it enough to just say that at all of the points for which $F$ is $0$, $DF$ has rank $1$?  This would imply that we have a 2-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Yes, that's enough, as it's the definition of regular value (for constant rank $1$, anyway). In fact, $DF$ evidently has rank $1$ everywhere except $(0, 0, 0)$, so it's enough to show that $(0, 0, 0)$ is not in the level set. (By the way, given that your set is called $S^2$, probably you mean $\cdots+z^2 - 1$, not $\cdots+z^3 - 1$.)

Comment: There is not much to say but would one of you post an answer? I would do it but I don't think I should get upvotes for other people's work.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys.  There is another statement of the regular value theorem which says we need to show that DF is a submersion.  How would we show that?